# TestCafe Studio custom action name

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm using TestCafe Studio Version 1.4.1 and using visual test recorder. I can't see any way to specify a descriptive name to each test action. I only get names like `Click` that do not tell me what was clicked. Ideally I would like to add a name like `Clicked on submit` or other names.
Is it even possible to do this? If yes, how any samples.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment this functionality is not supported. Thank you for the idea. We'll consider it with the team but we can't promise we will be able to implement it though.